# How to downgrade Ubuntu 16.04.7 to 16.04.6

Tags: 16.04, downgrade

I'm having trouble installing Xilinx Vivado 2020.1 in Ubuntu 16.04.7. The supported versions by Xilinx are: Ubuntu 16.04.5, 16.04.6 and some other non-16.04 Ubuntu point releases as shown in the screenshot.
Is it possible to downgrade the system to 16.06.6?

Xilinx Vivado 2020.1 installation Not Supported OS error:

[image: Xilinx Vivado 2020.1 installation Not Supported OS error]

Comment: `apt` and like packaging tools are designed to automatically upgrade to later packages, going backwards is all manual. The easy fix is restoration of a prior backup you've created. FYI: Ubuntu 16.04.7 only contains security fixes, so you're better in my opinion, trying to fix the issues & staying on 16.04.7.

Comment: The 16.04.5 & 16.04.6 mentioned likely just means they were the latest releases when the document you copied that detail from, was written or last updated. There should be no difference with 16.04.7; so it's likely a dependency or other issues we can likely help you with, if you provide the commands & actual messages you get when you attempt the install.

Comment: I added an error screenshot to my original post. I found a many information how to install Vivado 2020.1 in batch mode but it doesn't successful for me. Therefore, i'm try to understand maybe it's better and easy to downgrade my Ubuntu to 16.04.6.

Comment: @kostya.an “I found a many information how to install Vivado 2020.1 in batch mode but it doesn't successful for me.” Again, please by detailed. Please [edit] your post to add the output of the commands you run. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.

Comment: @kostya.an Which part of "You can still proceed with the installation by clicking 'OK'" is not clear? Which errors do you really have after the installation? Are some libraries missed, or so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to downgrade to previous version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363930/how-to-downgrade-to-previous-version)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to downgrade from 16.04.7 to 16.04.6 or 16.04.5. It would break too many packages. Instead of downgrading from 16.04.7 to 16.04.6 it's possible to download [Ubuntu 16.04.5](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.5/) and replace 16.04.7 with 16.04.5 by selecting the Erase Ubuntu 16.04 and install Ubuntu 16.04 option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer.

Unfortunately this will will completely erase your current Ubuntu installation with all programs and settings. If you are willing to take this drastic step please backup your stored personal files first. Don't select the *Download updates while installing* option in the Ubuntu installer, otherwise it will undo all your work by updating Ubuntu 16.04 while installing it.

Then you will be able to install Xilinx Vivado 2020.1 in Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Alternatively instead of installing Ubuntu 16.04.5 you can also install the more up-to-date [Ubuntu 18.04.4](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/) which also supports Xilinx Vivado 2020.1. You can even install Ubuntu 18.04.4 inside Ubuntu 16.04.7 as a guest OS running in a virtual machine application like VirtualBox.

Comment: If "replace 16.04.7 with 16.04.5 by selecting the Erase Ubuntu 16.04 and install Ubuntu 16.04 option in the Installation type screen of the Ubuntu installer" will completely erase my current Ubuntu installation with all programs and settings? Unfortunately, installing 18.04 is not an option for me.