# how to downgrade to previous version

Tags: 18.04, downgrade

I upgraded OS using following command

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Which upgrade
to

> PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

from

> PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"

Now I would like to go back to previous state:

> PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"

how to downgrade ?

Comment: You cannot: Those older packages are no longer in the Ubuntu repositories. If you have a complete set of those older packages in your local /var/cache/apt/archives, you could...but it doing so would be both painful and pointless. Your system would *automatically* upgrade back to 18.04.6. You should ask about whatever problem you are encountering that leads you to believe such a downgrade is a desirable solution.

Comment: What is your problem? Please check [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you are using ZFS as the file system, you could restore a previous snapshot. If the system is running with storage provided by a SAN, it may also be possible to restore a previous snapshot. If neither of these situations fit your installation, then you will not be able to roll back. As pLumo asks, what’s the problem you want to solve? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to downgrade from 18.04.6 to 18.04.4. It would break too many packages. Instead of downgrading from 18.04.6 to 18.04.4 it's possible to download [Ubuntu 18.04.4](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/) and replace 18.04.6 with 18.04.4 by selecting the Erase Ubuntu 18.04 and install Ubuntu 18.04 option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer.

Unfortunately this will will completely erase your current Ubuntu installation with all programs and settings. If you are willing to take this drastic step please backup your stored personal files first. Don't select the *Download updates while installing* option in the Ubuntu installer, otherwise it will undo all your work by updating Ubuntu 18.04 while installing it.